# Using IIS to give domain name to external site

Tags: networking, iis, subdomain, website, domain-name

At my workplace we are currently hosting our own website on a windows server using IIS. We've now had a new public website created by our marketer using SquareSpace and we want to be able to point our current domain name to the SquareSpace site.

The problem is that the website isn't the only thing our domain name is used for, it's also used for our VPN and a variety of other services so we can't just redirect of domain name registrar. Is there a way to configure IIS so it will redirect web requests to the new site and still keep the VPN, etc functioning with the same domain name?

I apologise if this is a very simple request, I have very little experience in Systems Administration and have tried to find the answer myself but struggling to even know what to search for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into setting up your dns in a consistent manner using [sub-domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain).

To start with you could have your website respond to `www.example.com` only and redirect `example.com` in IIS using http redirection.

But you should really be using sub-domains specific for each action.

- vpn.example.com
- mail.example.com
- www.example.com

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect) might help you, assuming you've IIS version 7 or higher.

The  element configures settings for Internet Information Services (IIS) 7 that redirect client requests to a new location.